# Error in receiving broadcast 

Tags: android

I am trying to create auto-install App for non-market users . I am downloading APK file from private Service and trigging it for installation . Now once the installation process is complete i want know this programmatically , so that i can delete the APK file .
   Now Problem is that i am not able to receive a broad Cast `ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL` . My code is not going inside onReceive.

```
  try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL("http://url/Downloads/App.apk");

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"App.apk");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
               // updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
        //catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override 
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)){
                Toast.makeText(AndroidActivity.this,"Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION"));
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".AndroidActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to register for `ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and check whether the install was your package in the reciever(to avoid reacting to some other package being added ) using

```
packagename = intent.getdata().getSchemeSpecificPart()
```

Then delete your apk

Comment: yes i agree with you but my real problem is i am not able to go inside onReceive

Comment: even for changed and added intents?

Comment: i have removed the if condition in onReceive .

Comment: the doc says ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL was never used. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL

Comment: yes , because " This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system." as per doc